# Fabric JS won't let me draw a dot in microsoft edge if I set the line width below 6

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, microsoft-edge

If I set the "line width" in Fabric JS free draw below 6 and try to draw a dot (just a single click of the mouse) in Microsoft Edge it won't appear, but it does in chrome and firefox.

Example code:

```
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;
```

I get the same problem on the fabric js website's free draw demo.

[Fabric JS Free draw demo](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing)

Is there a way to be able to draw a single dot (ie not a line) in fabric JS at a line width below 6 in Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 0):

> If I set the "line width" in Fabric JS free draw below 6 and try to
>   draw a dot (just a single click of the mouse) in Microsoft Edge it
>   won't appear, but it does in chrome and firefox.

I have reproduced the problem on my side, perhaps this issue is related to the fabricjs, I suggest you could feedback this issue to [them](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues).

Besides, as a temporary workaround, when you want to draw a dot, you could try to change the Line width to "6" or change the Drawing mode to "Spray" or "Circle".